# Is it possible to set the background of a asp.net gridview cell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

Is it possible? I can only set the background COLOR of a cell. Thing is, if i set the backgroundcolor it won't show (by default) when you print the page. So i wanted to set the background via css to the grid cell but can't find this property in the BoundField.ItemStyle class (Only 'backgroundColor'). So, is this possible somehow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

      if(condition)//Replace with your condition
      {
        e.Row.Cells[5].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/test.png) no-repeat 5px center
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you J_Ocampo

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

On RowDataBound event in the code behind, you can get the System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell object for the cell you need, and set its style using the CssClass property:

```
e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "myStyle"
```

Comment: [] brackets instead of ()   e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "className";

Comment: Now we have both VB and C# solutions. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `RowStyle-CssClass` property on the GridView, and then apply the style to the cell from where ever you have your CSS styles (external stylesheet, in the head, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it per cell instead of row on the grid view you would add

```
ItemStyle-CssClass="class name here"
```

Comment: Just realized it was for bound data not .net